# bjam `Unable to find file or target named 'libboost_python'`

Tags: python, boost, ubuntu, boost-python, bjam

What am I missing in my Boost.Python configuration/installation?

I'm trying to compile tutorial example, and I get error with `libboost_python` not found

```
cd /usr/share/doc/libboost1.42-doc/examples/libs/python/example/tutorial
bjam
error: Unable to find file or target named
error:     'libboost_python'
error: referred from project at
error:     '.'
```

But the library is there, `ldconfig.real` has been run:

```
/usr/lib/libboost_python.a -> libboost_python-py27.a
/usr/lib/libboost_python-mt-py26.a -> libboost_python-py26.a
/usr/lib/libboost_python-mt-py26.so -> libboost_python-py26.so.1.42.0
/usr/lib/libboost_python-mt-py27.a -> libboost_python-py27.a
/usr/lib/libboost_python-mt-py27.so -> libboost_python-py27.so.1.42.0
/usr/lib/libboost_python-py26.a
/usr/lib/libboost_python-py26.so -> libboost_python-py26.so.1.42.0
/usr/lib/libboost_python-py26.so.1.42.0
/usr/lib/libboost_python-py27.a
/usr/lib/libboost_python-py27.so -> libboost_python-py27.so.1.42.0
/usr/lib/libboost_python-py27.so.1.42.0
/usr/lib/libboost_python.so -> libboost_python-py27.so
```

I'm using default libboost packages from Ubuntu 11.04.

My `user-config.jam` is

```
using python : 2.7 ;
```

Comment: I believe default python would be 2.6, but your plain libboost_python is for python 2.7 -- so try setting the python version in user-config.jam to python 2.7, perhaps?

Comment: @Autopulated: added user-config.jam, no change

Comment: Oh, here's a thought: the build files for the tutorial might require the boost source code -- as if they are designed to be built along with boost. If you treat libboost_python as a plain old library (and maybe, dare I say it, ditch bjam) instead of as a `project' I think it should work. (I am by no means an expert on bjam though!)

Comment: @Autopulated: sounds kind of awkward, I mean, if that would need the source code, it'll install it as dependency. I suspect it's some env variable or something like that, which I have to set. But I don't know which exactly :-/

Comment: The environment variables important to bjam are `BOOST_ROOT` and `BOOST_BUILD_PATH`. I'm pretty sure that if you set the latter to a directory containing the boost source code it would just work ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Still not sure it that's the proper way, seems little hackish, but following helped:

In `Jamroot` file replaced

```
project
  : requirements <library>libboost_python ;
```

with

```
project
  : requirements <library>/usr/lib/libboost_python.so ;
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem on ubuntu 12.04 where I installed all the boost libraries as a package. I found the solution here:

http://jayrambhia.wordpress.com/2012/06/25/configuring-boostpython-and-hello-boost/

It turns out that you do not need to use bjam at all. A makefile suffices. I will repeat the the solution from the above link here:

1.) Install the libboost-python package

2.) Create a hello world source file called 'hello_ext.c':

```
char const* greet()
{
    return "hello, world";
}

#include<boost/python.hpp>
BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(hello_ext)
{
   using namespace boost::python;
   def("greet",greet);
}
```

3.) Create a makefile:

```
PYTHON_VERSION = 2.7
PYTHON_INCLUDE = /usr/include/python$(PYTHON_VERSION)
# location of the Boost Python include files and library
BOOST_INC = /usr/include
BOOST_LIB = /usr/lib
# compile mesh classes
TARGET = hello_ext
$(TARGET).so: $(TARGET).o
g++ -shared -Wl,--export-dynamic $(TARGET).o -L$(BOOST_LIB) -lboost_python -L/usr   /lib/python$(PYTHON_VERSION)/config -lpython$(PYTHON_VERSION) -o $(TARGET).so
$(TARGET).o: $(TARGET).c
g++ -I$(PYTHON_INCLUDE) -I$(BOOST_INC) -fPIC -c $(TARGET).c
```

4.) make

```
make
```

5.) Ready to use. In python:

```
import hello_ext
print hello_ext.greet()
```

Answer (score 0):

You could have a site-config file with something like the following ;

```
using boost : 1.48 : <include>/usr/include/boost-1_48 <library>/usr/lib ;
```

(you need the < library > bit, not sure why)

then you can do stuff like.

```
project foo 
        : <library>/boost//python
```

Makes things easier in the long run, as you inevitably will have to change boost version at some point.